Replicating Classic release pipeline setup on YAML
How do I achieve this kind of a setup on YAML:

I am specifically wondering about the artifact section. How do I achieve it? What I think I ought to do is have resources of the type pipelines and repositories declared before the stages, and then use DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 step on each job under each stage. But the way I see it,  that I will end up duplicating the code many times since we have many stages. Is there any way this can be achieved?
Or rather, do I create a separate stage for downloading the artifact and the repos, and the stages after it dependsOn it?
I just don't get it!

As stated in Automatic download in deployment jobs

All available artifacts from the current pipeline and from the associated pipeline resources are automatically downloaded in deployment jobs and made available for your deployment.

However, as per repository resources, a deployment job doesn't automatically clone the source repo. We need to explicitly define the source repo within your job with checkout
To avoid duplicating the code, you may consider using the ${{each}} expression in a YAML pipeline and inserting templates to expand steps , jobs, or stages if applicable. Here is a sample for your reference.
mainPipeline.yml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - DEV
  - QA
  - PROD

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: AnotherRepo # Not self
    type: git
    name: Repo1
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: UpstreamBuildPipeline
    source: PipelinePublishingArtifacts

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  - template: stageTemplate.yml
    parameters:
      env: ${{env}}

- stage: Stage_Downstream
  dependsOn:
  - ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
    - Stage_${{ env }}
  jobs:
  - job: Job_0
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: |
        echo "This is a traditional job. When no checkout steps are defined,"
        echo "The default behavior is as if checkout: self were the first step, and the current repository is checked out."
  - job: Job_1
    dependsOn: Job_0
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: AnotherRepo
    - download: UpstreamBuildPipeline

stageTemplate.yml
parameters:
- name: env
  default: ''

stages:
- stage: Stage_${{parameters.env}}
  dependsOn: [] # The stage is independent from other stages
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy_${{parameters.env}}
    environment: ${{parameters.env}}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        preDeploy:
         steps:
          - download: none
          - script: |
              echo "This is a deployment job. All available artifacts from the current pipeline and from the associated pipeline resources are automatically downloaded in deployment jobs and made available for your deployment."
              echo "To prevent downloads, specify download: none."
              echo "A deployment job doesn't automatically clone the source repo. You can checkout the source repo within your job with checkout: self."
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self
          - checkout: AnotherRepo
          - script: |
              tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
            displayName: Check repo resources
          # - download: UpstreamBuildPipeline
          - script: |
              tree $(Pipeline.Workspace)
            displayName: Check pipeilne resources
         




Thank you very much for this, but as you know, in the classic release definition/pipeline, we are allowed to choose the stages we want to release to - during run time ie. Is that achievable in this setup? If not, am I right in saying that it can be achieved by using parameters - pretty much as you've done?

One other question is that in mainPipeline.yml, why have you declared pipelines (under resources), and not builds? In the screenshot I shared, one of the artifacts is a build and the other three are repos. I am just super confused right now. Is it right to choose builds?

Per your follow-up query in the classic release definition/pipeline, we are allowed to choose the stages we want to release to, if you mean manually select the stages to deploy when creating a release, please check the similar functionality for a YAML pipeline to select Stages to run before manually triggering the pipeline. If there is any misunderstanding, please modify your original post and specify.

Per your question on pipelines/builds resources, you haven't shared a YAML definition demo, so I suggested the pipelines resources with deployment jobs. To me pipelines resources are more functional and useful in most scenarios. See this document for more details. The build resource artifacts aren't automatically downloaded in your jobs/deploy-jobs.

It is also advisable to post a new thread if you there is any specific issue when using YAML pipelines instead of posting follow-up queries in one single topic. It may be closed due to lack of focus. Let me know if your concern in this post can be resolved. Thx.
